# Auto resize to all resolutions

Tags: html, flash, web, resolution

I want to made a website in Flash but I have a big problem: I don't know how to resize it to all resolutions.

I tried to change "Match Movie" at HTML tab into "Percent" but didn't work because I still have white borders on the left side and right side!

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```